# Splitting a column with float numbers and add both int and decimal parts in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a column (version number) with more than 200k occurences as float for instance 1.2, 0.2 ...
I need to sum both sides of the floating number into a new column (total version), so that it gives me in the example 3, 2. Just integer numbers

Any advice?

Comment: `sum(map(int,str(1.2).split('.')))` Split using `.` map boh to integer and sum

Comment: Can you please specify what the result should be if the initial float array is `[1.2, 1.20, 1.020]`? Which "integers" do the fractional parts map to?

Comment: The question needs to be more clear, are numbers such as `1.02` allowed and what is the sum expected to be in this case?

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys for looking into it. The numbering just gives versions of documents (major being integer and decimal being minor versions) I don't care if major or minor, just want to sum both up. So to reply to @Stef, the results should be 3, 21, and the last is not possible. user2314737, that is not possible, it will be 1.2 (but not 1.02

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context? You say "I have a column (version number) with more than 200k occurences as float". Are you sure these are encoded as float? What do you mean "I have a column"? Is this in a csv document? In that case it's text, not floating-point values. "Floating-point" is a particular way of encoding numbers, and not appropriate for version numbers.

Comment: hi @Stef: yes, I imported the dataset from an excel doc (sharepoint extract with sharegate). when I call the .info() that column appears as float64: Version number                    210015 non-null  float64. Some examples of values in that column are: 0.1, 0.17, 1.0, 1.2, 2.0,2.12...Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should be very easy to understand. I can make a oneline also you want to have that.

```
mylist = [1.3, 2.6, 3.1]

number = 0
fractions = 0

for a in mylist:
    (a,b)=str(a).split('.')
    number = number + int(a)
    fractions = fractions + int(b)

print ("Number: " + str(number))
print ("Fractions: " + str(fractions))
```

This gives:

```
Number: 6
Fractions: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

### Do not use `str(x).split('.')` !

The one comment and the two other answers are currently suggesting to get the integer and fractional parts of a number `x` using

```py
i,f = (int(s) for s in str(x).split('.'))
```

While this does give a result, I believe it is a bad idea.

The problem is, if you expect a meaningful result, you need to specify the precision of the fractional part explicitly. `"1.20"` and `"1.2"` are two string representations of the same number, but `20` and `2` are two very different integers. In addition, floating-point numbers are subject to precision errors, and you could easily find yourself with a number like `"1.19999999999999999999999"`, which is only a small rounding error away from `"1.2"`, but results in a completely different result with this `str(x).split('.')` approach.

One way to avoid this chaotic behaviour is to set a precision, ie, a number of decimal places, and stick to it. For instance, when dealing with monetary values, we're used to talk about cents; although 1.5€ and 1.50€ are technically both valid, you'll always hear people say "one euro fifty" and never "one euro five". If you hear someone say "one euro oh five", it actually means 1.05€. We always add exactly two decimal places.

With this approach, there is no chaotic behaviour of `1.2` becoming `(1,2)` or `(1,20)` or `(1,1999999999)`. If you fixed the number of decimal places to 2, then `1.2` will always map to `(1,20)` and that's that.

### A more standard way

Here are two standard ways of getting the integer and fractional parts of a number in python:

```py
x = 1.20

# method 1
i = int(x)
f = x - i
# i = 1 and f = 0.2; i is an int and f a float

# method 2
import math
f, i = math.modf(x)
# i = 1.0 and f = 0.2; i and f are both floats
```

(EDIT: There is also a third method, pandas' `divmod` function. See [user2314737's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63752676/3080723).)

Once you've done that, you can turn the fractional part `f` into an integer by multiplying it with the chosen power of 10 and converting it to an integer:

```py
f = int(f * 100)
# f = 20
```

Finally you can apply this method to a whole list:

```py
data = [13.0, 14.20, 12.299, 4.414]

def intfrac_pair(x, decimal_places):
  i = int(x)
  f = int((10**decimal_places) * (x - i))
  return (i, f)

data_as_pairs = [intfrac_pair(x, 2) for x in data]
# = [(13, 0), (14, 20), (12, 30), (4, 41)]

sum_of_integer_parts    = sum(i for i,f in data_as_pairs)  # = 43
sum_of_fractional_parts = sum(f for i,f in data_as_pairs)  # = 91
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
df['total_number']=[sum([int(i) for i in str(k).split('.')]) for k in df.version_number]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`divmod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html) on the column

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 0.1])                           

df                                                                      
#      0
# 0  1.2
# 1  2.3
# 2  3.4
# 3  4.5
# 4  0.1

df['i'], df['d'] = df[0].divmod(1)                                     

df                                                                     
# Out: 
#      0    i    d
# 0  1.2  1.0  0.2
# 1  2.3  2.0  0.3
# 2  3.4  3.0  0.4
# 3  4.5  4.0  0.5
# 4  0.1  0.0  0.1
```

To sum row-wise as integers (a *precision* is needed, here I use `p=1` assuming the original floats contain only one decimal digit) :

```
p = 1
df['s'] = (df['i']+10**p*df['d'].round(decimals=p)).astype(np.int)

df                                                                    
# Out: 
#      0    i    d  s
# 0  1.2  1.0  0.2  3
# 1  2.3  2.0  0.3  5
# 2  3.4  3.0  0.4  7
# 3  4.5  4.0  0.5  9
# 4  0.1  0.0  0.1  1
```

Sum by columns:

```
df.sum()                                                               
# Out: 
# 0    11.5
# i    10.0
# d     1.5
```

**Note:** this will only work for positive integers as for instance `divmod(-3.4, 1)` returns `(-4.0, 0.6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys. I finally managed in a quite stupid, but effictive way. Before splitting, I transformed it to a string:

```
Allfiles['Version'] = Allfiles['Version'].round(3).astype(str)
```

Note that I rounded to 3 digits because a number like 2.111 was transformed to 2.11099999999999999999

Then I just did the split, creating a new column for minor versions (and having the major in the original colum

```
Allfiles[['Version', 'minor']] = Allfiles['Version'].str.split('.', expand=True)
```

Then I converted again both files into integers and sum both in the first column.

```
Allfiles['Version'] = Allfiles['Version']+Allfiles['minor']
```

(My dataframe name is Allfiles and the column version, as you can imagine.